# How to pass multiple XML payloads in JMeter and identify the response time for each request

Tags: jmeter

I am working on MQ testing in JMeter. We have 150+ XML payloads with unique queue name to test the performance. Here i have couple of scenario's to be achieved.

First scenario :

Is it possible to test all the XML payloads in a single script instead of creating 150 scripts for each queue name and XML payloads. So every iteration it has to pick new XML Payload with respective queue name.

Second scenario :

I need to extract the response time for each unique request(150+) in Aggregate report. May i know how to achieve this in JMeter

Ex :
Request 1 - Q_reply(query name) - XML Payload1 = response time in Aggregate report
Request 2 - Q_out(query name) - XML Payload2 = response time in Aggregate report

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have these "XML Payloads" in form of XML files which live in some folder  - you can use

   - [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin to iterate the files and read the filename (or full path to the file) into a JMeter Variable
   - [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) to read the file contents
2. You can append the variable from the previous step holding the file name to the sampler label, this way each file will have its own sample result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, Thanks it's working. But when i tried to execute the XML payload i am getting below error.
 i am passing File to string function like this in my script : def payload = ${__FileToString(${payload},,)}

Error details : Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script27.groovy: 34: Unexpected input: '<' @ line 34, column 15.
   def payload = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: [Don't inline JMeter Functions into Groovy scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), if you need to read the file in a JSR223 Test element use something like: `def payload = new File(vars.get('payload')).text`. More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)